# Word VBA: share variable between ThisDocument class module and a regular module?

Tags: vba, variables, ms-word

In Word 2013, I need to share a variable (ccID) between ThisDocument and a regular module. Here's the code:

"Project (Toto)" → "Microsoft Word Objects" → "ThisDocument":

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Document_ContentControlAfterAdd(ByVal NewContentControl As ContentControl, ByVal InUndoRedo As Boolean)

    Static ccID As String
    Dim alertTime As Variant
    
    ' You can't affect document content while within this event, so save CC ID and create a timer that calls code to execute after the event has finished.
    ccID = NewContentControl.ID
    alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "UpdateContentControl"

End Sub
```

"Project (Toto)" → "Modules" → "Module1":

```
' Give any newly-added content control a yellow background for user-friendliness
' (Called by ThisDocument -> Document_ContentControlAfterAdd)

Public Sub UpdateContentControl()

MsgBox ("UpdateContentControl started")
    ActiveDocument.ContentControls(ccID).Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow

End Sub
```

When UpdateContentControl runs, ccID is out of context. How can I share a variable between code in ThisDocument and a regular module?

Comment: `NewContentControl.Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow` worked fine for me within the event handler - no need to defer the shading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked fine for me:

```vb
Public Sub Document_ContentControlAfterAdd(ByVal NewContentControl As ContentControl, _
                                           ByVal InUndoRedo As Boolean)

    NewContentControl.Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow

End Sub
```

However it looks like it clears the placeholder text, so here's how you can do it using OnTime:

ThisDocument:

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim LastCC

Public Sub Document_ContentControlAfterAdd(ByVal NewContentControl As ContentControl, ByVal InUndoRedo As Boolean)

    LastCC = NewContentControl.id
    Application.OnTime when:=Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), _
                       Name:="UpdateContentControl"

End Sub

Public Property Get LastAddedCC()
    LastAddedCC = LastCC
End Property
```

Module:

```vb
Public Sub UpdateContentControl()
    Dim id
    id = ThisDocument.LastAddedCC
    Debug.Print "UpdateContentControl started with id: " & id
    ThisDocument.ContentControls(id).Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow
End Sub
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks!

Typo: the code starting with `Option Explicit` goes into "ThisDocument", not "ThisWorkbook" since this is Word, not Excel.